# Finding the values of a line if it is is perpendicular to another

Tags: geometry

as the title suggests, i'm trying to find the value of a point () if another set of line is perpendicular to it but i find it pretty hard.Do i just use the slope intercept formula?.

> Consider the lines $\ell$1: 3x − y + 4 = 0 and $\ell$2: x + y + $\ell$ = 0. Find the value of  if $\ell$1 is perpendicular to $\ell$2

Comment: You should adjust slopes of lines to satisfy $m_1m_2=-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that two lines written in the form $y_1=m_1x+q_1$ and $y_2=m_2x+q_2$ are perpendicular if $$m_1\cdot m_2=-1$$
Using this fact, we can say that:
$$y_1=3x+4 \land y_2=-\frac{1}{k}x-\frac{1}{k}l, k\neq 0$$
So, we have:
$$3\cdot\frac{1}{k}=-1 \leftrightarrow k=-3$$
And so the second line becomes:
$$x-3y+l=0$$

Comment: @Xardous: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Comment: Hi!, ive never seen some of the symbols you've used in your explanation, what is ∧ and ↔ ?

Comment: $\land$ denotes the logical operator "and" and $\leftrightarrow$ denotes the double logical implication (if and only if)